# Why do i get a black patch on my map and how do i get rid of it?

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I have a list of locations and values, and i am trying to add these locations to a map.
To do this I am using the `get_map` function from the `ggmap` package to download maps from google.
This is my code:

```
ggmap(get_map(location = c(left = 35.13, bottom = 31.72, right = 35.25 , top = 31.84)))
```

This is what i get:
[image]

Comment: Minimized your example.

Comment: OK i played with it a little and i see that if i set the maptype to be  "roadmap" the black patch disappears

Comment: Nice. Post this as an answer to your own question.

Comment: @tonytonov Thanks, but still I would like to see if it can be fixed using a terrain map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411178/google-static-terrain-maps-with-black-rectangles and seems to be an issue with the Google Static Maps api which ggmaps uses to generate these maps. I'm guessing the layer data is unavailable for some reason and it's defaulting to black.

A [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6289) has been started by the poster of that question which you can add your example to.